# Android force BarCode scanner to scan only BarCodes

Tags: android, android-camera, barcode, surfaceview, barcode-scanner

I have an Android app, where it simply scans the Barcode and this is working fine.

The problem is, sometimes if I have my phone during scanning turned to carpet in my room, or even a PC keyboard, it scans it and shows random numbers. The app thinks that it is some kind of Barcode and throws a random number.

The code works perfectly with Barcodes, but it scans also some other surfaces randomly (not always, but happens quite often).

Part of my code:

```
  private void initialiseDetectorsAndSources() {

        BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.EAN_8 | Barcode.EAN_13)
                .build();

        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1920, 1080)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .build();

        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

                try {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(AddOsivo.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
                    } else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AddOsivo.this, new
                                String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });


        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {
            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(@NonNull Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                final SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
                if (barcodes.size() != 0) {

                    barcodeText.post(() -> {

                        barcodeData = barcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue;
                        barcodeText.setText(barcodeData);
                        toneGen1.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ONE_MIN_BEEP, 150);

                        cameraSource.stop();

                        EditText ean = findViewById(R.id.barcode_text);
                        String eantext = ean.getText().toString();


                         });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

As you can see, I tried to use `setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.EAN_8 | Barcode.EAN_13)` which should limit the scanner to all Barcode types only, so I am not sure, why it thinks, that my keyboard or carpet is a barcode :)

Using this detector library:

```
import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should probably mention which `BarcodeDetector` you are using / along with library version.

Comment: I updated my question with the library I am using - gms.vision

Comment: Not even an autistic person has numbers on their carpet... while you're using a deprecated library [`Barcode`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/barcode/Barcode). The `Detector` should be able to tell the type of barcode and therefore permits to discard irrelevant results - and excessive amounts of results. So it takes in all information and one has to discard the irrelevant data later on (just alike a human being with hyper-vision would).

Comment: I have no numbers on the carpet, just multiple colors :D Just the apps scans it and shows numbers as it was the Barcode, but it is a carpet :) But thank you for your note, I did not realize the Barcode is deprecated. Hm, seems I need to completely rework it using ML-Kit, or leave it for now hoping people will not to try scanning their carpets...

Comment: You should provide a sample image of the surface which decodes. In image processing there is always a chance of error, especially with a live camera/per frame decode. If you can't alter the library, consider something decoded if done multiple times.

Comment: well, hard to provide a sample image, because it differs and it is random. Also if I turn the camera to my PC keyboard, sometimes it is scanned too, so not only the carpet. But it is very random, not just like it scans immediately, maybe just from some angle or so. And sometimes it doesn't scans it at all. Seems it can be a side effect of image processing in some cases as you wrote